# Calling yyrestart function in bison with no arguments causing sigsev on El Capitan

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm curious about the function signature for yyrestart - namely in the lexer file I see that the signature is:

```
void yyrestart  (FILE * input_file )
```

In my code I use yyrestart to flush the buffer, but I haven't been passing it any argument, it's just been empty:

```
yyrestart();
```

Which is currently working on every system we test on except for the latest version of OS X. Stepping through with GDB, it's clear on my rhel machine that just calling with no argument sets the file pointer to NULL:

```
yyrestart (input_file=0x0) at reglexer.c:1489
```

Whereas on El Capitan it comes through as garbage, which is causing the mem error later in generated code:

```
yyrestart (input_file=0x100001d0d) at reglexer.c:1489
```

I can't for the life of me figure out where yyrestart() is defined. Is there some macro in yacc/flex that defines the behavior for calling yyrestart with no arguments? If not, how is this even compiling?

*********** EDIT to Clarify the Compiling Question ************

As a small snippet to see what I'm talking about - this is what I have in a my .y file, which is executing the parser (this is a SLIGHT modification of what's [this example](https://github.com/eholum/automake_bison_example/blob/master/src/parcalc.y#L67)):

```
int main() {

FILE *myfile = fopen("infile.txt", "r");

if (!myfile) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open infile.txt\n");
    return 1;
}

calcYYin = myfile;

do {
    calcYYparse();
} while (!feof(calcYYin));

calcYYrestart();
return 0;
}
```

I can build that repository with whatever I want passed in as arguments to calcYYrestart() on that line. Substituting

```
calcYYrestart('a', 1, 5, 'a string');
```

still lets me compile the entire program using make (but a get a segv with bad input). But looking through the generated parcalc.c file, I don't see anything that would allow me to call calcYYrestart with anything except for a file pointer. I only see this as the prototype:

```
void calcYYrestart  (FILE * input_file );
```

Where's the magic happening with the compiler that lets me put whatever I want as arguments to that generated function?

Comment: Okay, clearly yacc and bison have some magic in them that just lets them compile no matter what's in the generated c files? I'm still kind of new to C so I don't know how that would work - but if I just put gibberish at the top of my lexer.c file and run gcc on it it still compiles...

Comment: you're probably not compiling the right way then. I recommend that you post a complete program, the steps you take to compile it, the behavior you expect, and also the behavior you are getting. Then your problem will be verifiable.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. I tried to adjust something that I wrote before to simulate what I'm talking about. Hopefully that little code snippet at least makes the compiling issue more clear... I'm just building everything using automake, and I don't why bison generated functions seem to support taking arbitrary arguments. Is there some c magic there that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting C to gently lead you through the maze, holding your hand, chiding you when you err and applauding your successes.

These may not be unreasonable expectations for a language, but C is not that language. C does what you tell it to do, nothing more, and when your instructions fall short of clarity, it simply lets you fall.

Although, in its defense, you can ask it to be a bit more verbose. If you specify `-Wall` on the command line (at least with gcc and clang), the compiler will provide you with some warnings. [See note 1.]

In this case, it probably would have warned you that `calcYYrestart` was not declared, which would make it your responsibility to get the arguments right. The function is declared and defined in the lexer, but here you are using it in the parser, which is a separate compilation unit. You really should declare it in the parser prologue, but nothing will enforce the correctness of that declaration. (C++ would fail to link in that case, but C does not record argument types in the formal function name.)

---

It's worth noting that there are many problems with the sample code you are basing your work on. I'd suggest looking for a better bison/flex tutorial, or at least reading through the sections in the flex manual about how input is handled.

Here, I've added some annotations to the original example, which shows the `calc.y` bison input file:

```
/* This is unnecessary, since `calcYYparse` is defined in this file.
extern int calcYYparse();
*/

extern FILE *calcYYin;

/* Command line arguments are always good */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /* If there is an argument, use it. Otherwise, stick with stdin */
    /* There is no need for a local variable. We can just use yyin */
    if (argc > 1) {
        calcYYin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!calcYYin) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't open infile.txt\n");
            return 1;
        }
}
/* calcYYin = myfile; */

/* This loop is unnecessary, since yyparse parses input until it
 * reaches EOF, unless it hits an error. And if it hits an error, it
 * will call calcYYerror (below), which in turn calls exit(1), so it
 * never returns.
 */
/* do { */
    calcYYparse();
/* } while (!feof(calcYYin)); */
    return 0;
}

void calcYYerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! %s\n", s);
    /* Valid arguments to `exit` are 0 and small positive integers. */ 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Of course, you probably don't want to just blow up the world if you hit a syntax error. The intention was probably to discard the rest of the line and then continue the parse. In that case, for obvious reasons, `callYYerror` should not call `exit()`.

By default, after `yyerror` is called, `yyparse` returns immediately (after cleaning up its local storage) with an error indication. If you want it to instead continue, then you need to use an `error` production, which would be the best solution.

You could also simply call `yyparse` again, as in the example. However, that leaves an unknown amount of the input file in the flex buffer. *There is no reason to believe that the buffer contains exactly the rest of the line in error.* Since flex scanners typically read there input in large chunks (except for interactive input), resetting the input file with `yyrestart` will discard a random amount of input, leaving the input file pointer at a random position in the file, which probably does not correspond with the beginning of a new line.

Even if that were not the case, as with unbuffered (interactive) input, it is entirely possible that the error was detected *at* the end of a line, in which case the new line will already have been consumed. So discarding to the end of the current line will result in discarding the line following the error.

Finally, the use of `feof(input)` to terminate input loops is a well-known antipattern, and should be avoided in favour of terminating when an EOF is encountered while reading input. In the case of flex-generated scanners, when EOF is detected, the current input is discarded, and then (if `yywrap` doesn't succeed in creating a new input), the `END` indication is returned to the parser. By then, `yyin` is no longer valid (because it was discarded), and calling `feof` on it is undefined behaviour.

---

#### Notes

1. You get even more warnings by also specifying `-Wextra`. And you can make the compiler a little stricter by telling it to use the latest standard, `-std=c11`, instead of the 1989 version augmented with various gcc extensions, mostly now outdated.)

Comment: Well, I'm not going to lie that would like C to be a little more loving than it is. And that does answer the compilation question - but I am still curious as to why the program above runs, and run successfully moreover, when the function call so clearly does not match the prototype. When the program reaches calcYYrestart(), I see very clearly in the gdb output the value of the file as null: (gdb) calcYYrestart (input_file=0x0). I guess I understand why it compiles... but why doesn't it barf on that line?

Comment: @Erik: It's Undefined Behaviour (UB) which means that what actually happens is dependent on too many factors to give an answer. But in broad terms, on most platforms a function expects its first argument to be in a specific register, which it is allowed to modify. Since the caller thinks that the function doesn't expect that register to contain anything, it doesn't do anything to set up the value, so it will be whatever it happened to be before. If that happens to be a FILE*, things will unexpectedly work; whether that is good or bad luck depends on your interpretation.

Comment: @Erik: In any case, this is as good a time as any to learn that you should never, ever, ever compile a program you are developing without appropriate compiler flags. If you don't use -Wall, you are working with one hand tied behind your back, and you are also not in a position to provide sufficient information to people trying to help you.

Comment: @Erik: I somewhat grumpily added a large complaint about the extremely poor example code you are basing your work on. I didn't really want to answer a question not being asked, but feel free to ask a separate question if you want to know how to best handle syntax errors in an interactive calculator.

Comment: Note the last paragraph of my edit. Possibly what is happening (other than on OS X) is that `calcYYin` has been set to NULL when the input buffer is discarded, so `feof(calcYYin)` effectively calls `feof(NULL)`. If `feof` detects that case and immediately returns true, then the register containing the first argument will still be NULL when `calcYYrestart()` is called. However, that is *pure speculation*, and could only be verified by generated code inspection. And it doesn't matter. Avoid the problem by writing correct code.

Comment: Thanks for the super helpful comments. I kind of dove into C and parsing pretty recently - and have been trying to fill in knowledge top down. Really I need time to go through all the documentation in a much more comprehensive manner. Your edits above are greatly appreciated - and answered a few more questions of mine. I'll probably come back in a while after getting more time to look at this and ask something more intelligent. In the interim - I'll adjust my compiler flags and try to just write better code from the start.